# How do I launch a game for windows that I installed?

Tags: installation, games

I managed to install a game for Windows using Wine (I think), but it doesn't show in the Applications/Games folder or in the Ubuntu Software Center. Did it really install? How do I find it?

When I was running the Setup, I believe the game installed in the C:\Games\Freespace directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The games installed via Wine don't go to Applications/Games. Instead they go under Applications/Wine/Programs/

Following is a screenshot of a generic Wine menu in Ubuntu/GNOME.

[image: wine menu]

Comment: What if the user is using 11.04's new Unity interface?

Comment: @WarriorIng64 then it would be in `~/.wine/drive_c/program\ files/ ...` somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Applications installed through wine are placed under Applications->Wine, so look for it in Wine menu

Alternatively, the wine drive C corresponds to `/home/$USER/.wine/drive_c`, so look for it in

```
~/.wine/drive_c/Games/Freespace
```

Comment: So, do something like: wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Games/Freespace/Freespace.exe from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Unity, you could try simply searching for "Freespace" in the launcher.

If it doesn't show up, try opening your home folder (first icon in the Unity dock), hit Control-L, type `.wine/drive_c` and you should see the contents of the Windows C: drive. Then just navigate to wherever it's installed and run it. You could also try to drag it to the Unity dock to have it easily accessible, but I'm not sure whether it works like this.