# How to play civilization 5 on ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: video, games

I have a 295 gtx video card from nvidia with 1700 MB of video memory, my Proc is a AMD 1100 hexcore clocked at 3.2 Ghz and I have 4 GB of RAM.

I dual boot my machine with windows 7. I have been using UBUNTU more now that 11.10 came out I'm still learning the ins and outs I have seen that people play CiV 5 on ubuntu I believe I have the right hardware but I just hope some one can help me with installing my favorite gam I don't want to go to win 7 just to play my game I don't want to run win 7 in virtual box.

So if there is another way to play my game let me know.

I installed playonlinux on my ubuntu 11.10 machine.

how do I use the thing?

Comment: Wine, Play on Linux?.. have you instlled them? have you go to appdb.winehq.org/ , and looked for your game?.

Comment: I installed playonlinux. the program does not show in my application menu. how do I use the program. I installed my game cd in the drive and right click and the only option I have is wine. But it didn't work with wine.

Comment: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=12117

Comment: According to appdb the game should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Have you got it working yet?

If not, please install Wine, then install the game by simply starting Setup.exe from the DVD.

If installation goes well, simply [start the game](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55679/how-do-i-launch-a-game-for-windows-that-i-installed). The Wine AppDB states that DirectX 11 mode does not work but that DirectX 9 works.

Answer (score 0):

A port for Civilization 5 is available for Linux through Steam and as long as you have it in your Steam Library you should be able to install it normally using the Linux Steam client.

Source can be found here: [Civilization 5 on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/8930/).